# How to fix "The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' "

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, cors

I'm working on a project and i'm using ReactJs for the frontend and Laravel 7 for the backend.

Apparently the `'Allow-Origin'` header in the response is still returning `"*"` even though I configured Cors in Laravel, every time I make a request with axios I get this error `"The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'"` and yes, I use withCredentials because in the Laravel documentation it says that we must allow credentials.

PS: Please, don't mark it as duplicate, I checked the previous questions and our problems are a little bit different and I couldn't find a useful answer

This is my config/cors.php file

```
'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie', '/login'],

'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins' => ['http://127.0.0.1:3000'],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

'exposed_headers' => [],

'max_age' => 0,

'supports_credentials' => true,

 ];
```

This is the middleware Cors.php file

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
        return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://127.0.0.1:3000')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', "PUT, POST, GET, DELETE, OPTIONS")
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', "Accept, Authorization, Content-Type")
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', "true");
}
```

Comment: You probably forget to run  php artisan route:clear to apply your changes.

Answer (score -1):

Possible reasons:

- httaccess
- CORS authorization to the header using Apache
- laravel Cache